# Check if number has passed certain boundary

Tags: java

I have a Thermostat that calls `tempChange(oldTemp, newTemp)` when the temperature changes by 0.1*C which is too frequent for my use case. I want to add an `if()` to filter out when the temperature has hits or passes a half or whole degree.

I am not sure how I would even begin with coding `hasNewTempPassedHalfOrWholeDegree(oldTemp, newTemp)`.

```
public void tempChange(Double oldTemp, Double newTemp) {
    if (hasNewTempPassedHalfOrWholeDegree(oldTemp, newTemp)) {
        // temperature is valid to process
    }
}
```

A valid temperature change would be one where the new temperature has passed a half or whole degree (ie: 20.0, 20.5, 21.0, 21.5). In other words, as @Aioros as worded: I am trying to find the "interval between the two temperatures [that] includes a whole number or a whole number + 0.5.".

Example of temperature timeline and expected results:

```
{ oldTemp:19.7, newTemp:20.0 } // valid
{ oldTemp:20.0, newTemp:20.2 } // not valid
{ oldTemp:20.2, newTemp:20.6 } // valid
{ oldTemp:20.6, newTemp:21.7 } // valid
{ oldTemp:21.7, newTemp:21.6 } // not valid
{ oldTemp:21.6, newTemp:21.5 } // valid
{ oldTemp:21.5, newTemp:21.2 } // not valid
{ oldTemp:21.2, newTemp:20.2 } // valid
{ oldTemp:20.2, newTemp:20.1 } // not valid
```

Comment: Can you elaborate why the example `{ oldTemp:19.7, newTemp:20.0 }` is considered valid when the differential is only `0.3`?

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS A single invocation with a difference of 0.1 between `oldTemp` and `newTemp` is proof @Jon is subtracting.  He needs aggregate change analysis across many invocations.

Comment: Looks like you are checking if either: The part in front of the comma increased. Or: The part behind the comma was < 5 before and is now >= 5. Maybe you can work something out with this in mind

Comment: Sorry, I have updated my question to explain what qualifies as a valid new temperature.

Comment: I believe @Jon is trying to check if the interval between the two temperatures includes a whole number or a whole number + 0.5.

Comment: @Aioros You're correct. I'll update my question to better explain a valid new temperature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple (not elegant) way could be to convert your `Double` values to `BigDecimal` and iterate over the range checking if any value in between leaves a remainder of zero when divided by 0.5 using a classic for loop:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    double[][] test = {
        {19.7, 20.0}, // valid
        {20.0, 20.2}, // not valid
        {20.2, 20.6}, // valid
        {20.6, 21.7}, // valid
        {21.7, 21.6}, // not valid
        {21.6, 21.5}, // valid
        {21.5, 21.2}, // not valid
        {21.2, 20.2}, // valid
        {20.2, 20.1}, // not valid
    };
    for(double[] d : test){
        boolean b = hasNewTempPassedHalfOrWholeDegree(d[0],d[1]);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(d) + (b ? "valid" : "not valid"));
    }
}

static boolean hasNewTempPassedHalfOrWholeDegree(Double oldTemp, Double newTemp) {
    
    BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(oldTemp));
    BigDecimal y = new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(newTemp));
    
    BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal("0.1");
    BigDecimal h = new BigDecimal("0.5");
    
    if(x.compareTo(y) == 0){
        return false;
    }
    else if(x.compareTo(y) < 0){
        for (BigDecimal i = x.add(d); i.compareTo(y) <= 0; i = i.add(d)) {
            if (i.remainder(h).compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        for (BigDecimal i = x.subtract(d); i.compareTo(y) >= 0; i = i.subtract(d)) {
            if (i.remainder(h).compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I'm looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to test if a temperature change crosses a .0 or a .5 boundary.

```
private boolean hasNewTempPassedHalfOrWholeDegree(Double oldTemp, Double newTemp) {
    int oldTempInt = Math.round(10d * oldTemp);
    int newTempInt = Math.round(10d * newTemp);
    int start = Math.min(oldTempInt,  newTempInt);
    int end = Math.max(oldTempInt,  newTempInt);
    
    for (int index = start; index <= end; index += 10) {
        if (index % 50 == 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but your answer didn't meet my question's requirement as I am looking for when the interval between the two numbers include a whole number or whole number + 0.5.

Comment: @Jon: So, you're saying that 20.1 -> 20.9 is an invalid difference, while 20.9 -> to 30.0 is a valid difference?

Comment: Your scale is off by one decimal place. I changed the `10` in the `for()` from 10 to 1, and the `50` in the `if()` from 50 to 5. Then all the tests pass except for: `{ oldTemp:20.0, newTemp:20.2 }` and `{ oldTemp:21.5, newTemp:21.2 }`.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly what you're looking for, you could notice that the interval between two numbers `a` and `b` includes an integer or a integer-and-a-half when:

```
FLOOR(2*b) > FLOOR(2*a).
```

So your condition would look like:

```
if (Math.floor(2*newTemp) != Math.floor(2*oldTemp)) {
    // valid
} else {
    // not valid
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but your answer didn't meet my question's requirement as I am looking for when the interval between the two numbers include a whole number or whole number + 0.5.

Comment: @Jon, that's exactly what this answer is trying to do. As far as I'm aware it gives the desired results on all your examples. What doesn't work?

Comment: When I ran my unit test, I had several failures: `{ oldTemp:21.6, newTemp:21.5 }` and `{ oldTemp:21.5, newTemp:21.2 }`.